# Route::match() not working in nested groups structure

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5

I'm creating an API that is available only via `POST`. I'm planning to have more than one version of the API, so the current one uses **v1** as part of the URL.

Now, in case an API call is made via `GET`, `PUT` or `DELETE` I would like to return a Fail response. For this I'm using `Route::match()`, which **works** perfectly fine in the code below:

```
   Route::group(['namespace'=>'API', 'prefix' => 'api/v1', 'middleware' => 'api.v1'], function() {

        Route::match(['get', 'put', 'delete'], '*', function () {
            return Response::json(array(
                'status' => 'Fail',
                'message' => 'Wrong HTTP verb used for the API call. Please use POST.'
                ));
        });

        // User
        Route::post('user/create', array('uses' => 'APIv1@createUser'));
        Route::post('user/read', array('uses' => 'APIv1@readUser'));
        // other calls

        // University
        Route::post('university/create', array('uses' => 'APIv1@createUniversity'));
        Route::post('university/read', array('uses' => 'APIv1@readUniversity'));
        // other calls...

    });
```

However, I noticed that I could group the routes even more, to separate the API version and calls to specific entities, like `user` and `university`:

```
Route::group(['namespace'=>'API', 'prefix' => 'api'], function() {

    Route::match(['get', 'put', 'delete'], '*', function () {
        return Response::json(array(
            'status' => 'Fail',
            'message' => 'Wrong HTTP verb used for the API call. Please use POST.'
            ));
    });
    /**
     * v.1
     */
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'middleware' => 'api.v1'], function() {

        // User
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'user'], function() {
            Route::post('create', array('uses' => 'APIv1@createUser'));
            Route::post('read', array('uses' => 'APIv1@readUser'));
        });

        // University
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'university'], function() {
            Route::post('create', array('uses' => 'APIv1@createUniversity'));
            Route::post('read/synonym', array('uses' => 'APIv1@readUniversity'));
        });
    });
});
```

The `Route::match()` in the code above **does not work**. When I try to access any API call with e.g. `GET`, the matching is ignored and I get **MethodNotAllowedHttpException**.

Can I get the second routes structure to work with `Route::match()` again? I tried to put it literally everywhere in the groups already. Putting the `Route::match()` outside of the hole structure and setting path to 'api/v1/*' does dot work either.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `post()` function you don't need to deny manualy other verb.

What you can do is to create a listener for the `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` and display what you want. Or you can also use `any()` function at the end of your route's group to handle all route that is not defined.

Comment: That's not really the point. The thing is to return a specific Response, only for those paths, only if the verb is not `POST`. And I would pretty much achieve it in **routes.php** than in a listener.

Comment: Sure, this is why I write that you cant handle all other request by using `any()` function.